# Resizing an "std::vector"; which elements are affected?

Tags: c++, vector, resize

```
std::vector<AClass> vect;
AClass Object0, Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4;
vect.push_back(Object0);    // 0th
vect.push_back(Object1);    // 1st
vect.push_back(Object2);    // 2nd
vect.push_back(Object3);    // 3rd
vect.push_back(Object4);    // 4th
```

**Question 1 (Shrinking):** Is it guarantied that the *0th*, *1st* and *2nd* elements are protected (i.e.; their values do not change) after resizing this vector with this code: `vect.resize(3)`?

**Question 2 (Expanding):** After expanded this vector by the code `vect.resize(7)`;
**a.** Are the first 5 elements (*0th* through *4th*) kept unchanged?
**b.** What happens to the newly added two elements (*5th* and *6th*)? What are their default values?

Comment: Note: Object0-4 are copied into the vector. Thus the value in the vector is distinct from the original value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, the standard says:

> ```
> void resize(size_type sz);
> ```
>
> If `sz < size()`, equivalent to `erase(begin() + sz, end());`.

Question 2: If no resizing is required, yes. Otherwise, your elements will be copied to a different place in memory. Their values will remain unchanged, but those values will be stored somewhere else. All iterators, pointers and references to those objects will be invalidated. The default value is `AClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

Yes, from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) "If sz is smaller than the current vector size, the content is reduced to its first sz elements, the rest being dropped."

Question 2:

a)  The first elements are kept unchanged, the vector just increases the size of it's internal buffer to add the new elements.

b)  The default constructor of AClass is called for the insertion of each new element.

Comment: What if the default constructor of `AClass` is private, and all of its available constructors are expecting at least one parameters?

Answer (score 1):

vector always grows and shrinks at the end, so if you reduce the size of a vector only the last elements are removed.  If you grow a vector with resize, new elements are added onto the end using the a default-constructed object as the value for the new entries.  For a class, this is the value of a new object created with the default constructormas.  For a primitive, this is zero (or false for bool).

And yes, elements that aren't removed are always protected during a resize.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you shrink a vector, all the objects that remain retain their prior values.

When you expand a vector, you supply a parameter specifying a value that will be used to fill the new slots. That parameter defaults to `T()`.