# Reducing the size of a std::vector without a default constructor

Tags: c++, stl

I have a templated class using a `std::vector` of it's template argument. The argument may not be default constructible. I want to **reduce** the size of the vector (cut it to a given size). Obviously

```
vec.resize( reduced_size );
```

...doesn't work as it requires a default constructor.

I could of course:

1. create the default constructor for any used type (which requires me to add it when it might not be a good design choice)
2. pass a default value to the function (useless clutter of the interface)
3. pass a construction method to the template (also useless clutter)

While writing the question, I noticed that I can `erase` the elements from the vector up to the end:

```
vec.erase ( vec.begin() + position, vec.end() );
```

... however, I'm not sure if this will be as efficient as `resize`.

Is there an efficient way to reduce a vector's size without a default constructor?

C++11 solutions are acceptable.

---

**EDIT:** Seems that both MSVC and GCC implement shrinking resize as a erase call, so that answers my performance question.

Comment: I don't see why erase should be less efficient. It will memmove 0 bytes, and otherwise be identical. Have you benchmarked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820998/resizing-an-stdvector-which-elements-are-affected

Comment: I'm still a C++ novice, but I don't understand why `T` would need a default constructor if shrinking.

Comment: @Prashant because `resize` doesn't know at compile time if the run time value passed to it is bigger or smaller than the existing `size` of the `vector`, so it has to be able to both grow and shrink.

Comment: @Yakk Gotcha, thanks for educating!

Comment: @Dave, I'm not at the point of benchmarking yet, but it is in a performance-fragile class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my implementation, it looks like we have (with a few simplifications):

```
void std::vector<T,A>::resize(size_type __new_size)
{
    if (__new_size > size())
        _M_default_append(__new_size - size());
    else if (__new_size < size())
        _M_erase_at_end(begin() + __new_size);
}

auto std::vector<T,A>::erase(iterator __first, iterator __last) -> iterator
{
    if (__first != __last)
    {
        if (__last != end())
            _GLIBCXX_MOVE3(__last, end(), __first);
        _M_erase_at_end(__first + (end() - __last));
    }
    return __first;
}
```

where `_M_...` are private member functions.  You really want the effects of `_M_erase_at_end`.  I would guess it would be hard or impossible for a compiler to optimize the `_M_default_append` call out of `v.resize(sz)`, but relatively easy to notice in `v.erase(iter, v.end())` that `__last == end()` and optimize away the `_GLIBCXX_MOVE3` and the `+ (end() - __last)`.  So `erase()` could very well be more efficient than `resize()` here.

I would expect most implementations to be a similar story: a few simple `if` tests, and then calling some identical method to call destructors for elements at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately in MSVC it seems to do otherwise and I need to be portable :/

Comment: The `erase` way IS portable. (From your question, it sounded like you already realized that.)  (Also, really? Their `resize()` calls copy constructors?)

Comment: Edited - it doesn't - surprisingly it calls the erase in the case of < size. But for > size it calls some MSVC bull* that seems to instantiate the requirement of a copy constructor.

Comment: At least that answers me that the local `resize` is also as effective as `erase` though :)

Comment: I think C++03 `vector` is allowed to require a copy constructor as soon as you type `std::vector<Thing>`, ignoring what methods you do or don't call. (C++11 is pickier.) I'm just a bit surprised at the choice of algorithm. I guess there are cases where each is better (but if I want to use N copy constructors, I can easily force that with other methods).

Comment: I do have default copy constructors in my problem case. I just didn't want to introduce a default constructor to make clear that the structure should be custom initialized. Accepted this answer cause it provided me the GCC implementation that I didn't have on hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your idea to use `erase` is the right route.  To reduce the amount of confusion, I would write a container based algorithm:

```
template<typename Container>
Container&& reduce_size( Container&& c, std::size_t amount ) {
  amount = std::min( amount, c.size() ); // paranoid!
  c.erase( end(c)-amount, end(c) );
  return std::forward<Container>(c); // I like my container-algorithms to pass through
}
```

which will be as fast as your `erase` implementation (well, one more branch and check).

Use:

```
std::vector< Foo > blah;
blah.emplace_back( 7 );
reduce_size( blah, 10 );
```

Comment: Upvoted. For my needs I'd probably use a cutoff with position than a reduce_size with amount though :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- when you call `resize`, you can supply a second parameter passing a value of the correct type that would (theoretically) be used to fill in the empty spots if you use `resize` to increase the size of the vector. In C++03, that argument has a default value of `T()`, which is where the default ctor comes into things (in C++11, they use overloading instead, so you can call `resize()` to reduce size without any further difficulty).

By passing a value of your own, you avoid the need for the default ctor. As noted above, in C++11, the default ctor won't be needed/used even if you don't pass the second argument.

I doubt this will give any real improvement compared to using `erase` though. In particular, the specification in the standard is (§23.3.6.3/9):

> If `sz <= size()`, equivalent to `erase(begin() + sz, end());`.

As such, there seems to be no real reason for any difference between `resize` and `erase` in this case.

Comment: I don't see how a `resize`, even without a second argument, could compile without some way to construct a default `T`?  Sure, it might no longer occur as a default parameter, but inside when the container gets bigger, it has to initialize the data with something.  And at compile time, the compiler doesn't know that the size parameter is smaller than what was there before...

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, if you increase the size of the collection, it inserts value-initialized elements, but this requires only CopyInsertable, not DefaultConstructible.

Comment: In C++11 with no second argument to `resize`, where is the `T` that you copy from coming from?

Comment: And, if a run time only branch requires constructing a `T` with no arguments, then the entire function requires that constructing a `T` must be possible.

Comment: @Yakk: Maybe I should have been a bit more clear -- I was essentially quoting the standard: "Requires: T shall be CopyInsertable into *this." (in the description of the single-argument `resize`).